# Joining (applying) a random row

Tags: sql-server, random

This is a query I am using to test how joining a random row works:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    Id = NEWID(),
    UserId = x.Id
FROM 
    sys.syscolumns
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [User] ORDER BY NEWID()) x
```

This is example of the result:

```
A45A30C7-9F11-4669-9477-81371B1F195A    47
49C460AE-E27E-402D-B958-2F1A9AC683E5    47
F538A29E-85EC-4FEE-9B5A-EAFEAF6D5BED    47
674CCA56-36D8-4EA1-83E5-D66827190875    47
80702A1C-8C0A-475A-A21E-001B880FE3E5    47
5897DFFE-3EA6-4CD4-BF67-97E23D4AD518    47
A49046CD-7EAF-4806-8A68-A3676A39DB2D    47
7A057F35-63F7-4FDF-B0EF-FCB80CFBB8DD    47
7C287C70-0743-4A74-AC16-5F23448BB420    47
3401B892-F61A-42EF-9B35-DF836184D205    47
```

Unfortunately all the rows applied from [User] table to sys.syscolumns are the same.

I also tried using `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` as a clause, it doesn't work.

It works if I add a weird clause like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    Id = NEWID(),
    UserId = x.Id
FROM 
    sys.syscolumns sc
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [User] u WHERE sc.name = sc.name ORDER BY NEWID()) x
```

I would like to know why.

Comment: As the subquery you have isn't correlates, the data engine is likely being "clever" enough to know that the subquery only need to be run once to get the result set. As a result, because it's only run once then you get the same row for *every* row in the outer query.

Comment: Side note, [`syscolumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscolumns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is an object for SQL Server ***2000*** databases; you should really be using [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) now.

Comment: @ThomA Hehe, yes, power of habit... And thanks for the answer, you are right - Compute Scalar operator shows a single execution :D Thanks, if you write a "proper" answer I will accept it.